# RadGrid with only horizontal scroll

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I am using RadGrid with paging 10, AllowScroll="true", width and no height. This gives what I need, that is a grid with only horizontal scroll and no vertical scroll. But the problem now is, if there is only one row in the grid, its shows blank space for 9 rows. My requirement is, its height must be wrapped to the rows available.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function GridCreated(sender, args) {
        var scrollArea = sender.GridDataDiv;
        var dataHeight = sender.get_masterTableView().get_element().clientHeight; if (dataHeight < 350) {
            scrollArea.style.height = dataHeight + 17 + "px";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then in the client settings area of your radgrid

```
<ClientSettings>
  <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated" />
</ClientSettings>
```

Answer (score 4):

Or if you don't want to worry about height calculation do this!

```
// radgrid scroll horizontal only

<ClientSettings>                    
    <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" />
    <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated" />
</ClientSettings>
```

//add below javascript function on the page

```
function GridCreated(sender, args) {
                 $('.rgDataDiv').removeAttr('style');
               $('.rgDataDiv').attr('style', 'overflow-x: scroll;');
            }
```